# Issues with random effects: what to do when analyzing sites with all 0's or all 1's?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, qq-plot

I'm analyzing data that looks at the survival of artificial bird nests under different treatments. These nests were grouped across 80 sites, with 6 nests per site. I have created a binomial model on R that looks something like this (simplified):

Nest survival ~ Treatment 1 * Treatment 2 + (1|Site), family = binomial.

The problem is, many of the sites have very little or no variation within them (all 0s or all 1s). That is, often all the nests did not survive or all the nests did survive at a site. I believe that this is leading to very funny looking qqplots and in some cases, very large model estimates. The models are all running, however, with no convergence issues.

I could reformat my data to get rid of the random effects (e.g. by creating a proportion of nests surviving out of 6 at each site). This clears up the qqplots and estimates etc. But I do have a treatment that I really want to test that is within site (i.e. categorical distance - 3 levels: 10m, 30m, 50m - to the center point of the site, where I have placed an attractant for predators). Also note, that the models I am currently running show that there is an effect of this treatment.

Does anyone have any advice on how to deal with this issue? And, is it actually an issue? If so, are there transformations or edits to my data that I can use? Should I be using a different "family"? Any advice is appreciated - I am at my wits end on this one!

Many thanks, Emma.